# macOS high sierra 10.13 AD Mobile acount issue

Tags: macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I am try to login to AD account in macOS high sierra 10.13 and getting error:-

**You are unable to log in to user account "skull" at this time 
Login in the account failed because an error occurred**

**System logs :**

> Oct  6 08:24:49 MyMac kcm[399]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?
>   Oct  6 08:24:50 MyMac authorizationhost[344]: ERROR | -[HomeDirMounter mountNetworkHomeWithURL:attributes:dirPath:username:] | PremountHomeDirectoryWithAuthentication( url=smb://IMASFRG-KS0099/skull%%98, homedir=/home/skull, name=skull ) returned 2

Comment: I didn’t down vote but your question should be moved to ask different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uncheck "Use UNC path from Active Directory to derive network home location". Here is a screenshot for your reference. Then you can map the drive via Enterprise Connect if your company had it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43TnO.jpg)